# Why don't compilers call destructor automatically when an object is declared using new operator?

Tags: c++, oop, destructor, new-operator

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class b {
    public:
        int *a;

    b (int val) {
        *a = val;
    }

    ~b() {
        cout << "destructor" << endl;
        delete a;
    }
};

int main() {
    b *obj = new b(1);
    cout << "end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
destructor
end
```

Received output:

```
end
```

In above code compiler don't call destructor when i make object using new operator but in case of normal object destructor is called successfully.
what is the reason behind it?

Comment: That's how C++ works.  You failed to call `delete b;`.  Now you see where memory leaks come from.

Comment: `new` means _"Let me deal with the lifetime of the object and its memory"_. If you want the C++ runtime to handle those automatically, create your object with `b obj{1};`. Note that you also have an error in the definition of `b` where you fail to reserve memory for `b::*a`.

Comment: If an object is created using a `new` expression, its destructor is *only* called during the corresponding `delete` expression  (or if the destructor is explicitly called for that object, but that's a highly specialised use case).   Unlike some other languages, C++ does not include garbage collection, in which all dynamically allocated objects are "cleaned up" if your code loses track of them and/or forgets to destroy them.

Comment: *"compiler don't call destructor"* -- at what point would you expect the destructor to be called? Keep in mind that one of the key benefits of dynamic allocation is that the object will survive the end of the function in which it was created.

Comment: You create *two* objects here - one is stored in variable `obj` and has type `b *` and another is the object pointed to by `obj` with type `b`. Compiler does call destructor for variable `obj` when it goes out of scope. It doesn't do anything with the object it points to.

Comment: Note that this `*a = val;` is completely wrong. The pointer `a` has not been initialized, therefore, you cannot dereference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three different reasons for creating an object with `new`; depending on why you do it, it may or may not be appropriate to delete it when done.

The primary one is that you want to manage its lifetime:

```
int *create(int i) {
    int *result = new int(i);
    return result;
}
```

Here, you don't want to destroy the `int` object when the function ends. Creating it with `new` means you have to take care of cleaning it up when you're done:

```
int main() {
    int *xp = create(3);
    std::cout << *xp << 'n';
    delete xp; // I'm done with it
    // more code can go here, but don't use xp
    return 0;
}
```

Another reason is that the object is an array, and you don't know its size at compile time, so you can't create it as an auto object:

```
void f(int size) {
    int my_array[size]; // illegal, although some compilers allow it, sigh
    int *my_ptr = new int[size]; // okay, creates array with size elements
    // code that uses my_ptr goes here
    delete[] my_ptr;
}
```

But that one really should be written with `std::vector<int>`, which relieves you of the burden of having to remember to delete the array when you're done:

```
void f(int size) {
    std::vector<int> my_array(size);
    // code that uses my_array
    // no delete, because no explicit new; my_array destructor handles the memory
}
```

And, finally, you might be dealing with an object that's so large you don't want to clutter the stack with it:

```
struct my_large_type {
    long double filler[32768];
};
```

Yes, you can create an object like this on the stack:

```
void g() {
    my_large_type x;
}
```

but having many of these things runs the risk of taking up more space than the stack can handle. So you can create them on the free store, with `new`:

```
void g() {
    my_large_type *xp = new my_large_type;
    // code that uses *xp goes here
    delete xp;
}
```

The danger here is that you might forget to delete the memory, or, perhaps worse, that the code between the `new` and the `delete` might throw an exception, so the delete doesn't happen -- the memory allocated by `new` has just leaked.

The right solution here is to use a smart pointer, so that you don't have to handle deleting the object yourself:

```
void g() {
    std::unique_ptr<my_large_type> xp = new my_large_type;
    // code that uses *xp goes here
    // no delete; destructor will do it for you
}
```

To summarize: the situations where you want to clean up the `new`ed object at the end of the block where it was created are best handled by not explicitly using `new`, but putting the responsibility into a class whose destructor will handle the cleanup. In these examples that would be `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr`. That leaves the case where you want to explicitly manage the lifetime of the object, because you don't know at the time you create it how long it should hang around. In that case, if you don't clean it up, it simply won't get cleaned up; you told the compiler you'd take care of it, and the compiler trusts you.